# Issue trying to do POST Operations using REST, Error 402, 405

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, request-digest

I am trying to do `POST` operations such update, create and delete items using rest and javascript. I am getting `402` Error mostly attributed this to having a wrong/corrupt `requestdigest` value.

When I tried out an ajax call to `http://<site url>/_api/contextinfo` - I get the error `405 - invalid method`

---

Code for Creating new Item -

```
function addNewItem(no)
{

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TestWF')/Items",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
      "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      _metadata: {        'type': 'SP.Data.TestWFListItem'      },
      Title: 'Test'
    }),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('ghhjgk');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      jQuery('#status').text( error.responseText)
    }
  });
}
```

error :

> -2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPExceptionThe security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.

---

Code for refreshing `requestdigest`

```
function updateReqDigest() {

jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        jQuery('#status').text( data.responseText);    }
});

}
```

Error :

> -1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceExceptionThe HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'GetContextWebInformation'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use correct HTTP method to invoke the resource.

I have also tried this :

```
var r = UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
alert(r);
```

No Error is thrown in this case, and `r` is undefined. Also, the value of `_spFormDigestRefreshInterval` is `14400` Is this the default value ?

---

**Update**

According to @Shekar's Answer, I replaced ajax Call with call through `SP.RequestExecutor`

When, I try to Create a new item in the list using `RequestExecutor` the success callback gets executed but the **item doesnt get created**.

When I try to update an existing item in `RequestExecutor`, I get an error -

> "A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=entry, application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose' matches the content type 'application/json'."

Comment: Just updated the answer

Comment: Right. Fair enough :)

Comment: Did you make sure you passed the correct Body data? I see only one underscore(_) in your code for _metadata. It needs to be two (__metadata)

Comment: i updated `_metdata` to `__metadata`, still the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was weirdly around conflict between multiple jQuery Files. The `$` pointed to the `jQuery Tools` code instead of `jQuery 1.11.x` instead. Hence, (I dont know how but ..) all the `$ POST` calls got resolved to `$ GET`

@Sekhar has a very nifty trick, that should ideally have circumvented the `$` issue but somehow it didn't. Thanks Sekhar

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issues with $.ajax and did it in a different way.
Here is my article about making REST calls.
I used OOTB SP.RequestExecutor Object in /_layouts/15/sp.requestexecutor.js. to make the post requests. It worked perfecctly in all environments.

[https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com](https://sharepointatwork.wordpress.com/2015/05/09/two-reasons-not-to-use-the-ajax-with-sharepoint-rest-calls/)

Comment: I made some progress with your answer but later found that it doesnt solve my issue.